# Print five point summary values(Min,Q1,Median,Q3,Max) on the boxplot

Tags: r

I am trying to create a simple boxplot with all the labels. I have a dataset that says about the Number of customer Visits .It has two columns; Customer ID and AvgVists

```
custID       AvgVisits
 1            10
 2             4
 3             12
```

I want a simple boxplot that is horizontally oriented and displays the five summary points on the graph, with nice color and axes. I am able to find the heading, make it horizontally oriented, unable to report the summary numbers on the graph itself.

Comment: First hit...http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+boxplot+min+max+median

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `text()` command, with the format `text(location, "print this text", pos)`. `pos` should be one of the following: 1=below, 2=left, 3=above, 4=right. If you need further assistance please include the code you have so far. More here: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html

Answer (score 1):

@Henriks link seems to answer your question. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977561/changing-layout-of-boxplot-and-adding-labels-to-it/) may also be helpful in terms of applying annotation to multiple boxplots on the same graph.

For completeness:

`boxplot()` will calculate the no.s (same as `fivenum()` ) to plot, which you can verify by storing the result:

```
AvgVisits <- c(10,4,12)
b1 <- boxplot(AvgVisits)
b1$stats == fivenum(AvgVisits)
```

Here's a solution with `ggplot2` which you may find appealing. Change the values of `aes(x=)` to move the position up/down (as co-ordinates already flipped).

```
require(ggplot2)
q1 <- qplot(x=1, b1$stats, geom = "boxplot")
q1 +coord_flip() +
    geom_text(aes(x=1.1,y=b1$stats,label=b1$stats)) +
    opts(
        axis.text.x=theme_blank(),
        axis.text.y=theme_blank(),
        axis.title.x=theme_blank(),
        axis.title.y=theme_blank()
        )
```

Giving:

[image: The result]

Comment: "opts" is now deprecated. Use "labs" instead. Same for "theme_blank()", use "theme_light()" or whatever theme you prefer.